# Combinations of a given array ordering them in different arrays so that there aren't doubles

Tags: ruby, combinations, calculation

I'm making a soccer tournament manager for children games.
There can be many rounds and each team in each round plays vs each other.
Given combinations of each round I need the calendar of matches, with the largest amount of teams playing simultaneously.
Is there a way to order the array of combinations to achieve the result?

I tried to "make" some algorithm but I wasn't able to find the best one.
In provided code it's guaranteed that two teams can play the same time but no more...

```rb
teams = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] # number of teams is variable

pairings = teams.combination(2).to_a
pairings.shuffle!
calendar = []
calendar << pairings.slice!(0)

while pairings.any?
    p = calendar.slice(-1)
    a = p[0]
    b = p[1]
    matched = false
    pairings.each do |pairing|
        next if pairing.include? a
        next if pairing.include? b
        matched = true
        calendar << pairings.delete(pairing)
        break
    end
    unless matched
        p1 = pairings.slice!(0)
        prev = false
        calendar.each do |pairing|
            if pairing.include?(a) || pairing.include?(b)
                prev = true
                next
            end
            unless prev
                i = calendar.index(pairing)
                calendar.insert(i, p1)
                break
            end
            prev = false
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Try goggling “round-robin tournament algorithm “.  [This](https://dev.mikamai.com/2016/07/20/create-a-round-robin-tournament-in-ruby/) May be relevant.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't found the right words to search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling the terms suggested I came to this solution, many thanks!

```rb
teams = [1,2,3,4,5]

teams.push "x" if teams.length.odd?

first = [teams.slice!(0)]

teams.length.times do
    half = Integer(teams.length / 2)
    row1 = first + teams.slice(0...half)
    row2 = teams.slice(half...teams.length).reverse
    for i in 0..half do
        next if row1[i] == "x"
        next if row2[i] == "x"
        puts "#{row1[i]} - #{row2[i]}"
    end
    teams.unshift(teams.pop)
end
```